# Retrieve DataFrame of all but one specified column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to select all but one column in a pandas DataFrame object? I've seen ways to delete a column, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

use `drop` method:

```
df.drop(column_name, axis=1)
```

Comment: what does axis = 1 mean here?

Comment: @uniquegino It instructs the function to search the column space when looking for the entity to drop. If `axis=0`, it will search the row space

Comment: @BrianVanover Thanks Brian!

Comment: I've always used this to permanently drop a column.  Never thought to use it for selection.  `scott.mind == "blown"`

Comment: Do not forget to add `inplace=True` or to assign it to a variable.

Comment: @Scott Does it permanently remove a column ? Or if I print dp` again I would have it again ?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica it doesn't modify the original `DataFrame` unless you specify `inplace=True`

Answer (score 89):

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != col]
```

where `col` is the name of the column to leave out.

Answer (score 20):

you can just select the columns you want without deleting or dropping:

```
collist = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df1 = df[collist]
```

Just pass a list of the columns you desire

You can also retrieve the list of columns and then select from that list

```
collist = df.columns.tolist()
# you can now select from this list any arbritrary range
df1 = df[collist[0:1]]
# or remove a column
collist.remove('col2')
# now select
df1 = df[collist]
# df1 will now only have 'col1' and 'col3'
```

Comment: Note: the question is for "all but one" columns not for selecting one column.

Comment: @YuShen my answer shows how to select an arbritrary list of columns, it is not showing how to select a single column.

Comment: @EdChum people seem to have been precipitate in downvoting this one.

Comment: @EricWalker it's only rep nothing major plus I know this is an answer that is correct, others are free to think different but it doesn't make me think I should delete or edit this answer. In fact dropping a column would delete the column if you assigned the result of drop to itself e.g. `df = df.drop(col, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
df[ df.columns[df.columns!='not_this_column'] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use numpy to build a mask:

```
import numpy as np
columns = df.columns
mask = np.ones(columns.shape, dtype=bool)
i = 4 #The specified column that you don't want to show
mask[i] = 0
df[columns[mask]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as an option, you can select all columns but one (or many) using a list comprehension and df.loc method:

```
select = [x for x in df.columns if x != "column_you_don't_want"]
df.loc[:, select]
```

In case you want to leave out more than one column you can try this:

```
columns_dont_want = ["col1", "col2"]
select = [x for x in df.columns if x not in columns_dont_want]
df.loc[:, select]
```

Comment: Don't do that. Do this `df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(["col1", "col2"])]`. Even then, just use `drop` with the list `["col1", "col2"]`.